# website returns error on wordpres request

Tags: wordpress, request, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

hello i'm trying a "problem" some days that doesn't interfere much in the functioning of the site but it bothers me a lot !!! and do not think where to disable or fix !!! I've done everything ...
the problem is my site (https://magistraldoces.com.br) is requesting 3 URLs ... the first is https://stats.wp.com/s-202013.js'%20defer='defer 
it returns code 301 ... the second is this https://wordpress.com/s-202013.js'%20defer='defer/ returns me 404 and the third https://wordpress.com/s-202013.js'%20defer='defer/ return me 404 too ...

[image]
https://www.webpagetest.org/result/200326_JP_5876abc959748cd6cad33c05e685925f/1/details/

tks a lot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Jetpack WordPress plugin which causes the error. You can try by disabling the Jetpack plugin for few minutes to resolving the issue.

Also, you will need to clear the cache from your site and Cloudflare.